# How can we place a logger statement inside an orElse() block?

Tags: java, kotlin, events, project-reactor

I have the following function that returns a `Mono`.

```
    fun performEvent(type: String, event: MyEvent, relId: UUID): Mono<MyBaseEvent>{
        return processorById.getOrDefault(type,null)!!.handleTask(event,relId)
           .map{
              kTamplate.send(getResultMessage(it))
              Mono.just(it)
            }.orElse(Mono.empty())  // a logger is required for orElse case
        
    }
```

Is there a way to add a logging statement inside the `orElse` at the end?

Comment: is `.orElse` called on an `Optional`? If yes you could use `.orElseGet { logger.log("whatever"); Mono.emplt() }`

Comment: Thanks @Lino for your quick response. Will try in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mono.defer` to log and create the empty `Mono`:

```
...orElse(Mono.defer{ 
   /* log here */
   Mono.empty()
})
```

Or, if it is okay that the logging is evaluated at the time of the `orElse` statement, you could just use `also`:

```
...orElse(Mono.empty().also { /* log here */ })
```

Moreover, if it is `Optional.orElse` you are using, you could just switch to `orElseGet`:

```
...orElseGet { 
   /* log here */
   Mono.empty()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since *map {...}* always returns a List, you could use *.ifEmpty()*.

This would be the case for a non-empty list:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b")

val result = list
  .map { it }
  .ifEmpty { 
    println("empty")   // will be skipped
    emptyList()        // will be skipped
  }

println(result)   // Output: [a, b]
```

And if the list is empty the same code would produce this:

```
val list = emptyList<String>()

val result = list
  .map { it }
  .ifEmpty { 
    println("empty")   // Output: empty
    emptyList() 
  }

println(result)   // Output: []
```

Comment: The `map` in the above code snippet is not `Iterable.map`, but `Mono.map`.

Comment: That is not the case.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right that it is not `Mono.map`, but it is definitely not a list `map`, because `List` does not have an `orElse` function. It is probably an `Optional.map`.

Comment: I don't understand: a) I do not have anything installed called Mono. b) Why would this not be a List? The input list is definitively a List, the result also, and you could insert a line like _.also { println(it::class.qualifiedName) }_ after _.map { it }_ and it will output _java.util.ArrayList_.

Comment: Yes, this may be true for your answer, but not for the question.